# Facebook graph API not returning posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've successfully authenticated a user using FB and am trying to use the graph API to access their posts. However, I'm only able to access the `email` field and no `posts` field is returned at all.

Relevant Code:

```
FB.api(
        '/me',
        'GET',
        {"fields":"email,posts"},
        function(response) {
            console.log("Succes: ",response);
        }
      );
```

Response:

```
Success:  { email: 'example@email', id: 'example_id' }
```

However the equivalent code on the graph API explorer returns

```
{ posts: {example_posts}, email: 'example@email', id: 'example_id' }
```

I'm not receiving any errors, simply no `posts` response. The same thing happens with fields such as `feed` and `albums`.

Something else worth noting is that when I add a field such as `thisIsNotAField` the API returns an error. Why is it silently failing for certain fields?

Comment: `posts` is not a field is a connection. You should do `/me/posts`

Comment: @WizKid This returns an empty object { data: [] }. However, using that syntax on the graph API interface returns the posts.

Comment: Then the user has not granted user_posts permission

Comment: How do I prompt the user to grant that permission? I'm testing on the app administrator's Facebook page so shouldn't those permissions be granted?@WizKid

Comment: You use Facebook Login. It is explained in the documentation.

Comment: _“However the equivalent code on the graph API returns”_ – I assume you actually mean the Graph API Explorer here (because your request is “on the graph API” as well, because that API is what you are using)? Well then you probably did not select your own app in there, but created a token that includes the necessary permissions for the Graph API Explorer app only.

Comment: @CBroe, you're right. That was a typo. I meant to refer to the graph API explorer.